# Error when calling function that returns HTML within email template

Tags: haskell, ihp

### Context

I generated a standard email template via the IDE. Since I want to dynamically build an HTML table within the email, I added a function that takes a list and returns HTML. However, calling it from within the email's main `[hsx|...|]` results in the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘context’ with ‘ControllerContext’
        arising from a functional dependency between constraints:
          ‘?context::ControllerContext’
            arising from a use of ‘renderList’ at Admin/Mail/Accounts/Report.hs:(16,35)-(47,6)
          ‘?context::context’
            arising from the type signature for:
                           IHP.MailPrelude.html :: forall context.
                                                   (?context::context, ConfigProvider context) =>
...
```

The function returning `Html` itself compiles fine, but calling it from within the instance's `[hsx|...|]` results in a compiler error.
The called function can have no arguments and the result is the same. What triggers it is when the function returns `Html`. `String` or `Text` is fine.

Using IHP Pro 1.0.0.

### Example

```hs
module Admin.Mail.Static.Test where
import Admin.View.Prelude
import IHP.MailPrelude

data TestMail = TestMail { user :: User }

instance BuildMail TestMail where
    subject = "Subject"
    to TestMail { .. } = Address { addressName = Just "Firstname Lastname", addressEmail = "fname.lname@example.com" }
    from = "hi@example.com"
    html TestMail { .. } = [hsx|
        Hello World
        {renderFoo}
    |]

renderFoo :: Html
renderFoo = [hsx|foo|]
```

### Question

I can use functions to generate snippets of HTML in other (non-email) views with no problem so why does it not work here?

Comment: Mind sharing the `renderList` function?

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal reproducible example. Turns out it has nothing to do with the list argument. Calling any function that returns `Html` causes the compiler error. The function that returns `Html` itself compiles fine.